# Scrape part of a table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My code so far looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
html = open("Greyhound Race and Breeding1.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table")

output_rows = []
for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
  columns = table_row.findAll('td')
  output_row = []
for column in columns:
  output_row.append(column.text)
  output_rows.append(output_row)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
  writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

This gets more than I want, I only want to get the part of the table that follows from a td with the title="order in which the dogs arrived at the finish". How can I modify my code to solve this?

My guess is that table = soup.find("table") should be modified so that I can find

```
    <td title="order in which the dogs arrived at the finish">.
```

But I don't know how. Maybe I should somehow set table to be the parent of the td with the

```
    <td title="order in which the dogs arrived at the finish">
```

```
<table> 
<tr>
  <td>I don't want this</td>
  <td>Or this</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table> 
<tr>
  <td>I don't want this</td>
  <td>Or this</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td title="order in which the dogs arrived at the finish"> I want this and the rest of  the document</td>
<td> More things I want</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

I almost got Jack Fleetings solution to work

```
html = open("Greyhound Race and Breeding1.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
#table = soup.find("table")["title": "order in which the dogs arrived at the finish"]

#table = str(soup.find("table",{"title": "order in which the dogs arrived at the finish"}))
table = soup.find("table")
for table in soup.select('table'):
    if table.select_one('td[title="order in which the dogs arrived at the finish"]')is not None:
                          newTable = table
output_rows = []
for table_row in newTable.findAll("tr"):
   columns = table_row.findAll("td")
   output_row = []
   for column in columns:
      output_row.append(column.text)
      output_rows.append(output_row)

with open("output8.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

The problem is that it repeats the same row several times, but it is the correct table. I tried several times to correct this,but no luck. So I decided to switch to using pandas instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd



df = pd.read_html("Greyhound Race and Breeding1.html")

#This shows how many tables there are
print (len(df)) 

#To find the right table, I bruteforced it by printing print(df[for each table]) #Turns out the table I was looking for was df[8]
print(df[8])

#Finally we move the table to a csv file
df[8].to_csv("Table.csv")
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code

Comment: You forgot to include your `html` code

Comment: The html code is a mess, and I don't see the need to include it. I think it should be enough to  know that I want to only scrape from a td with title="order in which the dogs arrived at the finish".

Comment: No you are wrong. We are not here to work for you, but to help you. Tell us what you tried, where do you think it failed and please try to make your code more readable.

Comment: It failed because I can't find the td with  title = "order in which the dogs arrived at the finish". I can transform the whole table to csv, but this brings a lot of junk that I don't need.

I suspect I need to change table = soup.find("table"), but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: @PatrikGustafsson Without seeing the HTML markup is hard to help you.

Comment: Which part of the table? first row?

Comment: I want everything from <td title="order in which the dogs arrived at the finish"> and onwards

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use css selectors to do this:

```
for table in soup.select('table'):
    target = table.select('td[title="order in which the dogs arrived at the finish"]')
    if len(target)>0:
        print(table)
```

If you know that only one table meets the requirement, you can use:

```
target = soup.select_one('td[title="order in which the dogs arrived at the finish"]')
print(target.findParent())
```

Output:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td title="order in which the dogs arrived at the finish"> I want this and the rest of  the document</td>
<td> More things I want</td>
</tr>
</table>
```